# Lockscreen widget doesn't work after a while

Tags: java, android, widget, lockscreen

Hi I'm programming a lock screen widget that is different buttons and a text that displays information, the widget works fine when it's add or when you "maximize" or "minimize"(full screen or half screen with pattern to unlock) and when the phone is just turned on, the problem is when the phone is ide for a while then the buttons doesn't do nothing, I read a lot of post about it but I haven't found my problem.
I have CyanogenMod 11 [4.4.2]

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.example.widget"
            android:label="magicButtons" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_provider" />
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.widgetReciber">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="updateW"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Widget.java (it's not exactly this):

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
    //Upgrade buttons
}
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context,AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds){
  super.onUpdate(context,appWidgetManager,appWidgetIds);
  //Upgrade buttons
}
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I just found the solution (which seems to be nowhere on the internet^^) after some hours of debugging. Android is apparently calling onAppWidgetOptionsChanged() whenever you lock your phone and the lockscreen widget is in collapsed state. This will recreate your widget.

To prevent your widget from becoming unusable you have to do the same stuff like you do in onUpdate().

Example:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager manager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for(int a = 0; a < appWidgetIds.length; a++) {
        manager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetsIds[a], createWidget());
    }
}

public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context, AppWidgetManager manager, 
        int appWidgetId, Bundle widgetOptions) {
    manager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, createWidget());
}

private RemoteViews createWidget() {
    //Create your Widget (aka RemoteViews) here! You might want to pass      
    //needed variables for creating the widget ;)
}
```